# How to configure tslint to check no-unused-variable in Angular2

Tags: angular, tslint

Do you know how to configure tslint to check no-unused-variable and also unsed imports in angular2, I have already added such two lines in my tslint file

```
"no-unused-expression": true,
"no-unused-variable": true,
```

But it's propably not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Add the two lines as you did, then run

```
ng lint --type-check
```